# props value is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

here is my Home.js file which is parent component

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Home.css"
import  { useState } from 'react'
import Quiz from './Quiz';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
export default function Home() {
    const [numQuestions, setNumQuestions] = useState(10);
    const [category, setCategory] = useState(9);
    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState('easy');
    const [type, setType] = useState('multiple');
    const navigate= useNavigate();
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        setSubmitted(true);
        console.log(numQuestions);
        console.log(category);
        console.log(difficulty);
        console.log(type);
        e.preventDefault();
       navigate('/quizz');
      };
  return (
    <>
     {submitted ? (<Quiz
    numQuestions={numQuestions} category={category} difficulty={difficulty} type={type}
 />):(<>
    <div className='intials'>
        <p>
            <h1 id='tophead'>Quizz Time</h1>
            Welcome to Quize time test your knowledge on various topics including sports,science,enviorment etc.
        </p>
    </div>
 <form  method="get" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>
    <div className='quiz'>
        Number of Question: <label htmlFor='noq'></label>
        <input type="number" name="noq" id="noq" min="5" max="20" value={numQuestions} onChange={(e) => setNumQuestions(e.target.value)} className='input'>
        </input>
    </div>
    <div className='quiz'>
    Select Category: <label htmlFor='category'></label>
        <select name='category'id='category' onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)} className='input'>
            <option value={category}>General Knowledge</option>
            <option value="10">Entertainment: Books</option>
            <option value="11">Entertainment: Film</option>
            <option value="12">Entertainment: Music</option>
            <option value="13">Entertainment: Musicals &amp; Theatres</option>
            <option value="14">Entertainment: Television</option>
            <option value="15">Entertainment: Video Games</option>
            <option value="16">Entertainment: Board Games</option>
            <option value="17">Science &amp; Nature</option>
            <option value="18">Science: Computers</option>
            <option value="19">Science: Mathematics</option>
            <option value="20">Mythology</option>
            <option value="21">Sports</option>
            <option value="22">Geography</option>
            <option value="23">History</option>
            <option value="24">Politics</option>
            <option value="25">Art</option>
            <option value="26">Celebrities</option>
            <option value="27">Animals</option>
            <option value="28">Vehicles</option>
            <option value="29">Entertainment: Comics</option>
            <option value="30">Science: Gadgets</option>
            <option value="31">Entertainment: Japanese Anime &amp; Manga</option>
            <option value="32">Entertainment: Cartoon &amp; Animations</option>     
        </select>
    </div>
    <div className='quiz'>
    <label htmlFor="difficulty">Select Difficulty: </label>
    <select name="difficulty" className="input" onChange={(e) => setDifficulty(e.target.value)} id='difficulty'>
            <option value={difficulty}>Easy</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="hard">Hard</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div className='quiz'>
    <label htmlFor="type">Select Type: </label>
    <select name="type" className="input" id='type' onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}>&gt;
            <option value={type}>Multiple Choice</option>
            <option value="boolean">True / False</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div className='quiz'>
        <button className="btn input" type="submit" >Generate Quiz</button>
        </div>
 </form>
 </>
      )}
</>
  );
}
```

and this is my qizz.js file which is childeren component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
export default function Quiz(props) {
  const { numQuestions, category, difficulty, type } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("value=",numQuestions)
      console.log("value=",category)
      console.log("value=",difficulty)
      console.log("value=",type)
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      // Process the data here
    });
}, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        this is quizz{numQuestions}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

when I try to use the props value it shows that value is undefined specially    `console.log("value=",type)` there is also no error message in the console as well when I submit the form all values are easily seen in the console but after passing them as props I don't what is happening and why they do not show the value whereas it render the quizz page `<p> this is quizz{numQuestions} </p>` and shows "this is quizz" but not show {numQuestion}

can anybody suggest what i do

Comment: I have checked your code, it is getting logged in console

Comment: I dont see why your consoles would be empty. Can you post the logs?

Comment: as i  told there is no error in my console

Answer (score 0):

I generated a Sandbox with your code and it is getting logged in the console.

[image]

Play with it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-marco-v23mkv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: but it still shows value= undefine in my console as well as in the sandbox can you run it again and please tell me that after submitting the form is props value display on screen by the way thank for your effort

Comment: @Kamleshwar Is this resolve? Please comment your `console` so I could check which and where is `undefined`.